# MySQL - Select columns which match parameters

Tags: php, mysql, regex

In my table called `products` I have column `parameters` where are strings like this:

```
1#2#3#4=10#5=20#6
```

These numbers are IDs of parameters of products. Every ID is separate by `#`. Some of parameters are with `=` which mean, that this parameter has specific value (only integer).

So parameter with ID `4` has value `10`.

I want to select products which matching parameters saved in `$_GET["parameters"]`. Pattern of saved parameters is for example `2-6-5>10-4<5`. So example of string above does not match, because parameter 4 has value 10 and this is greater than 5

I know how to select products from table only with parameter IDs. Like this:

```
$parameters = explode("-", $_GET["parameters"]);
$search = "";

foreach ($parameters as $parameter) {
    if (preg_match("/^\d+$/", $parameter)) {
        $search .= "AND parameters LIKE '%#$parameter#%' ";
    }
}

$search = preg_replace("/^AND\s/", "", $search);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE $search";
...
```

But I do not know, how to solve this with parameters `5>10` and `4<5`. I want to get products which have parameters 2, 6, 5 greater or equal than 10 and 4 less or equal than 5. It is possible in MySQL? If yes, how?

Comment: Ew... If you're finding this hard to do, it's probably because you're doing it horribly wrong...

Comment: In addition to @NiettheDarkAbsol, why not give every product an `ID` with a **separate** column?

Comment: `LIKE` is NOT regex. It's more like glob.

Answer (score 0):

`LIKE` is very slow; performing it multiple times on the same field is terribly inefficient. Think of how the query could be nice and simple to generate and then create a data model that supports it. Something like

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
   WHERE prop2 NOT NULL
   AND prop6 NOT NULL
   AND prop5 < 10
   AND prop4 < 5
```

easy to read, easy to maintain, and fast. It implies that each of your properties is in its own column (which also enables indexing on your properties). It also allows you to use readable names for your properties which alone could save you hours of debugging.